# During running my app logcat looks horrible and i am unable to get anything:

Tags: android, android-studio

LogCat looks like:
I am unable to get anything why it is happening.I searched on google but i did'nt get anything.

```
11-02 17:44:54.303 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-02 17:44:54.342 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
11-02 17:44:54.824 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-02 17:44:54.841 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-02 17:44:54.856 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
11-02 17:44:54.883 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-02 17:44:54.942 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-02 17:44:54.954 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
11-02 17:44:55.025 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-02 17:44:55.042 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-02 17:44:55.051 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
11-02 17:44:55.076 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-02 17:44:55.095 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-02 17:44:55.113 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
11-02 17:44:55.129 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-02 17:44:55.137 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-02 17:44:55.142 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
11-02 17:44:55.366 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-02 17:44:55.379 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-02 17:44:55.383 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
11-02 17:44:55.430 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-02 17:44:55.441 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-02 17:44:55.450 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
11-02 17:44:55.485 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-02 17:44:55.498 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-02 17:44:55.502 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
11-02 17:44:55.570 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-02 17:44:55.579 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-02 17:44:55.585 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
11-02 17:44:55.612 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-02 17:44:55.621 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-02 17:44:55.630 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
11-02 17:44:55.649 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-02 17:44:55.661 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-02 17:44:55.667 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
11-02 17:44:55.694 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-02 17:44:56.022 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-02 17:44:56.028 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
11-02 17:44:56.070 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-02 17:44:56.075 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-02 17:44:56.079 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
11-02 17:44:56.098 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-02 17:44:56.102 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-02 17:44:56.109 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
11-02 17:44:56.125 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-02 17:44:56.526 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-02 17:44:56.530 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
11-02 17:44:56.713 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-02 17:44:56.722 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-02 17:44:56.728 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
11-02 17:44:56.746 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-02 17:44:56.751 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-02 17:44:56.764 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
11-02 17:44:56.848 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-02 17:44:56.860 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-02 17:44:56.864 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
11-02 17:44:56.890 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-02 17:44:56.896 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-02 17:44:56.903 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
11-02 17:44:56.982 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-02 17:44:56.996 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-02 17:44:57.001 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
11-02 17:44:57.028 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-02 17:44:57.031 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-02 17:44:57.039 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
11-02 17:44:57.062 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-02 17:44:57.079 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-02 17:44:57.085 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
11-02 17:44:57.179 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-02 17:44:57.185 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-02 17:44:57.189 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
11-02 17:44:57.201 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-02 17:44:57.206 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-02 17:44:57.215 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
11-02 17:44:57.233 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-02 17:44:57.369 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-02 17:44:57.372 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
11-02 17:44:57.453 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-02 17:44:57.458 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-02 17:44:57.462 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
11-02 17:44:57.477 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-02 17:44:57.480 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-02 17:44:57.485 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
11-02 17:44:57.507 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-02 17:44:57.823 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-02 17:44:57.832 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
11-02 17:44:57.908 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-02 17:44:57.914 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-02 17:44:57.919 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
11-02 17:44:57.931 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-02 17:44:57.935 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-02 17:44:57.940 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
11-02 17:44:57.957 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-02 17:44:58.037 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-02 17:44:58.042 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
11-02 17:44:58.120 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-02 17:44:58.127 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-02 17:44:58.131 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
11-02 17:44:58.146 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-02 17:44:58.150 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-02 17:44:58.156 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
11-02 17:44:58.171 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-02 17:44:58.367 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-02 17:44:58.371 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
11-02 17:44:58.477 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-02 17:44:58.483 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-02 17:44:58.489 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
11-02 17:44:58.503 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-02 17:44:58.508 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-02 17:44:58.519 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
11-02 17:44:58.534 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-02 17:44:58.861 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-02 17:44:58.869 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
11-02 17:44:58.912 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-02 17:44:58.919 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-02 17:44:58.923 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
11-02 17:44:58.937 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-02 17:44:58.940 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-02 17:44:58.944 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
11-02 17:44:58.961 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-02 17:44:59.012 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-02 17:44:59.019 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
11-02 17:44:59.105 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-02 17:44:59.118 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-02 17:44:59.121 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
11-02 17:44:59.137 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-02 17:44:59.139 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-02 17:44:59.146 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
11-02 17:44:59.176 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-02 17:44:59.201 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-02 17:44:59.220 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
11-02 17:44:59.301 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-02 17:44:59.308 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-02 17:44:59.312 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
11-02 17:44:59.328 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-02 17:44:59.335 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-02 17:44:59.342 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
11-02 17:44:59.454 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-02 17:44:59.468 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-02 17:44:59.472 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
11-02 17:44:59.502 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-02 17:44:59.509 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-02 17:44:59.519 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
11-02 17:44:59.617 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-02 17:44:59.631 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-02 17:44:59.637 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
11-02 17:44:59.670 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-02 17:44:59.674 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-02 17:44:59.680 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
11-02 17:44:59.695 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-02 17:45:00.025 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-02 17:45:00.033 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
11-02 17:45:00.073 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-02 17:45:00.077 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-02 17:45:00.080 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
11-02 17:45:00.093 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-02 17:45:00.100 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-02 17:45:00.104 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
11-02 17:45:00.121 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-02 17:45:00.139 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-02 17:45:00.148 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
11-02 17:45:00.191 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-02 17:45:00.197 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-02 17:45:00.201 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
11-02 17:45:00.214 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-02 17:45:00.526 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-02 17:45:00.531 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
11-02 17:45:00.574 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-02 17:45:00.578 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-02 17:45:00.582 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
11-02 17:45:00.606 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-02 17:45:00.609 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-02 17:45:00.615 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
11-02 17:45:00.631 6115-6266/com.example.android.buyhatke E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-02 17:45:01.023 6115-6115/com.example.android.buyhatke W/IInputConnectionWrapper: requestCursorAnchorInfo on inactive InputConnection
11-02 17:45:01.027 6115-6115/com.example.android.buyhatke W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
11-02 17:45:01.028 6115-6115/com.example.android.buyhatke W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
11-02 17:45:01.030 6115-6115/com.example.android.buyhatke W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
```

and it(above code) is repeating my numbers of time.
I am new to android.so,i am unable to understand much.
Please help.
Thanks

Comment: I tried to search in your mind about what your code looks like, but didn't succeed either...

Comment: I agree with @Orabîg, I have no idea what you are expecting the logs to look like.